# js address specific element

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a search function on a specific text with verses, which is structured like the sample text below.
The 1st line of each verse has got a verse number at the beginning.
My search function works fine. It searches for a word and saves the whole line in which the word occurs in an array and prints it in the "rslt" element. 
Now I would like to save the verse number of the found line and if it doesn't have one, than it should take it from the line above.
Have you got an idea how I could achieve this?

```js
function srch() {
  var input, filter, p, cache, resultEl;
  input = "MTV";
  cache1 = [];
  resultEl = document.getElementById('reslt');
  p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (p[i].innerHTML.indexOf(input) > -1) {
      cache1.push(p[i].innerHTML); /*save results in array*/
    }
  }
  if (cache1.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < cache1.length; i++) {
      resultEl.innerHTML = resultEl.innerHTML + cache1[i] + "<br>"; /*write results*/
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button onclick="srch()">Search</button></div>
<div id="reslt"></div>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">1 </span>The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</p>
<p class="xline"> DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog.</p>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">2 </span> Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps.</p>
<p class="xline"> Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs.</p>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">3 </span> Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex!</p>
<p class="xline"> Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz.</p>
<p class="xline">Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox.</p>
<p class="xline">Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack.</p>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">4 </span>Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. </p>
<p class="xline">Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.</p>
```

Comment: You don't need jsFiddle - you can use [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using `.previousElementSibling`.

Test to see if there is a `<span>` tag, if so, the verse # is there,
otherwise concatenate the previous element's HTML with the search result
Then push the result onto your array,

Check comments in code in `srch()` function:

```js
function srch() {
  var input, filter, p, cache, resultEl;
  input = "MTV";
  cache1 = [];
  resultEl = document.getElementById('reslt');
  p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (p[i].innerHTML.indexOf(input) > -1) {
      // if it includes a span, it includes the verse #
      if (p[i].querySelector('span')) {
        cache1.push(p[i].innerHTML); /*save results in array*/
        // otherwise, get the previous siblings HTML too
      } else {
        cache1.push(p[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML + p[i].innerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
  if (cache1.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < cache1.length; i++) {
      resultEl.innerHTML = resultEl.innerHTML + cache1[i] + "<br><br>"; /*write results*/
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button onclick="srch()">Search</button></div>
<div id="reslt"></div>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">1 </span>The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</p>
<p class="xline"> DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog.</p>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">2 </span> Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps.</p>
<p class="xline"> Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs.</p>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">3 </span> Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex!</p>
<p class="xline"> Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz.</p>
<p class="xline">Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox.</p>
<p class="xline">Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack.</p>
<p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">4 </span>Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. </p>
<p class="xline">Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would create a new function to a find a verse number and it would be something like this

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
      
function srch() {
        var input, filter, cache, resultEl;
        input = "MTV";
        cache1= [];
        resultEl = document.getElementById('reslt');
    
        for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            if (p[i].innerHTML.indexOf(input) > -1) {
                cache1.push(p[i].innerHTML); /*save results in array*/
                var verseNumber =  findVerseNumber(i);
                console.log(verseNumber)
            }
        }     
     
      
        if (cache1.length>0){
            for (i = 0; i < cache1.length; i++) {
                resultEl.innerHTML = resultEl.innerHTML + cache1[i]+"<br>"; /*write results*/
            }
        }
    }


 function findVerseNumber(index){
      var verseNumber;
      for (j = index; j >= 0; j--) {
           if (p[j].querySelector('span')) {
            verseNumber = p[j].querySelector('span').innerHTML.trim();
              break;
          } 
        }  
      return verseNumber;
    }
```

Html

```
<div><button onclick="srch()">Search</button></div>
        <div id="reslt"></div>
        <p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">1 </span>The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</p>
        <p class="xline"> DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog.</p>
        <p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">2 </span> Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps.</p>
        <p class="xline"> Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs.</p>
        <p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">3 </span> Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex!</p>
        <p class="xline"> Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz.</p>
        <p class="xline">Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox.</p>
        <p class="xline">Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack.</p>
        <p class="1stline"><span class="verse-nr">4 </span>Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim. </p>
        <p class="xline">Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.</p>
```